# How to force the labels to fit in VennDiagram?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I use VennDiagram to make a venn diagram with the following example code:

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn.diagram(list(shams_90d = 1:3, shams_90d_4h = 2:4, sham3__shams_90d = 3:5,
             sham3_90d__shams = 5:7, sham3_90d__shams_4h = 6:9),
             fill = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"),
             alpha = c(0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 0.5), cex = 1,cat.fontface = 2,
             lty =1, filename = "trial2.emf");
```

Which gives this figure:

[image]

The names on the left and right of the figure are cut off, and a little bit of the name at the bottom as well. I tried changing width, but that makes the venn diagram itself get wider, and the names still get cut off.

How can I make the VennDiagram so that it includes the full names, either by adding more whitespace on the left and right of the diagram, or by pushing the names more towards the venn diagram?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can justify the label text with `cat.just`. The package reference manual gives info. on how to pass the parameters.

For your example i used trial and error for the justification values.

```
# Plot
v <- venn.diagram(list(shams_90d = 1:3, shams_90d_4h = 2:4, sham3__shams_90d = 3:5,
                   sham3_90d__shams = 5:7, sham3_90d__shams_4h = 6:9),
              fill = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"),
              alpha = c(0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 0.5), cex = 1,cat.fontface = 2,
              lty =1, filename=NULL, cat.cex=0.8, 
              cat.just=list(c(0.6,1) , c(0,0) , c(0,0) , c(1,1) , c(1,0)))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v)
```

[image]

Another option (if a bit of a quick hack) would be to remove the `cat.just` argument and set a smaller `grid::viewport`. You may need to tweak the width of your graphics window / output device (ie `pdf(..., width=...)`):

```
# Plot
v <- venn.diagram(list(shams_90d = 1:3, shams_90d_4h = 2:4, sham3__shams_90d = 3:5,
                   sham3_90d__shams = 5:7, sham3_90d__shams_4h = 6:9),
              fill = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"),
              alpha = c(0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 0.5), cex = 1,cat.fontface = 2,
              lty =1, filename=NULL, cat.cex=0.8)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=unit(0.8, "npc"), height = unit(0.8, "npc")))
grid.draw(v)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to do this automatically because I'm generating hundreds of venn diagrams?

Comment: Probably. but I suspect it could get tricky matching which labels are to be justified. A quick hack could be to set a smaller `grid::viewport`. So using the example without the `cat.just` line:  `grid.newpage() ; pushViewport(viewport(width=unit(0.8, "npc"), height = unit(0.8, "npc")));
grid.draw(v)` . You may need to tweak the width of your graphics window / output device (ie `pdf(..., width=...)`) . Might be worth asking a new question for more thoughts.

Comment: Tried what you suggested and fixed the problem