# VennDiagram: rotate category label

Tags: r, venn-diagram

With `VennDiagram` package in R, when the length of category label is big, one solution is rotating the category label at some degree. However, current version of `VennDiagram` seems don't support this. Is there some alternative method to do this?

The alternative method is using the parameters, including `cat.pos`,`cat.just`,`cat.dist`,`cat.cex`. To some extant, the problem can be resolved, but it will be better to implement rotation. Just like the `srt` parameter in `par`.

Thank you!

Comment: there are a couple of options that may help shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234439/how-to-force-the-labels-to-fit-in-venndiagram/22826211) , also `cat.pos` may additionally help.

Comment: Hi, @user20650, thank you for your comment. I will have a try.